# MongoEngine: Operator "__contains" does not work with non-english letters or words

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

When trying to use Q(nickname__contains="") from mongoengine.queryset.visitor, mongoengine will not match the non-english character.

For instance:

> {
>
> ```
> "nickname":"你好啊"
> ```
>
> }
>
> => User.objects(Q(nickname__contains="你好")).first()
>
> => None

But with English letters, this will work:

> {
>
> ```
> "nickname":"Hello"
> ```
>
> }
>
> => User.objects(Q(nickname__contains="Hel")).first()
>
> => (User Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't seem to have the issue, at least with recent version of mongoengine (tested with 0.16.3).

Note that you can also use the `__raw__` parameter in `.objects` to issue a raw pymongo query

See below:

```
class TestUser(Document):
    nickname = StringField()

TestUser(nickname="你好啊").save()

TestUser.objects(nickname__contains="你好").first()  # prints <TestUser: TestUser object>

TestUser.objects(__raw__={"nickname" : {"$regex" : ".*你好.*"}}).first() # prints <TestUser: TestUser object>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the issue was with Mongoengine, but it's actually not. I was using an old version of data. Thanks again.